# Selecting an image isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got some troubles working on javascript for an Firefox OS app, so I hope anyone can help me.

The case is I append some images from javascript (see code)

```
var aux = "<img class=\"imageOn\" id=\"" + imageName + "\"" + "src:\"" + imageURL + "\" >";
var image = "<a class=\"imageOn\" href=\"#\"> " + aux + " </a>";
$("#categoriasList").append(image);
$('#'+imageName).attr('src',imageURL);
```

And now I want to select one of these images from another js file:

```
$("img.imageOn").bind('click', function(e) {  
  console.log($(this).attr('id')); 
  playText($(this).attr('id'),"es");
  // Change to picturesView
  // Load icons from category choosed
});
```

The point is that actually it isn't working, the event is not triggered, so apendding or selecting the images has to be wrong, but I don't find the error. Does anyone know how to fix it? 
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using the event handler "on" of query

Answer (score 2):

Your `src` attribute should be followed by a `=` not a `:`

```
"<img class=\"imageOn\" id=\"" + imageName + "\"" + "src=\"" + imageURL + "\" >";
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
"src:\"
```

Should probably be

```
"src=\"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `=` instead of `:` in your `src`. Try this:

```
"<img class=\"imageOn\" id=\"" + imageName + "\"" + "src=\"" + imageURL + "\" >";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using jQuery you can use following method.

```
var aux= $(document.createElement('img')).attr(
 'id':imageName,
 'src':imageURL,
 'class':'imageOn'
),
image = $(document.createElement('a')).attr({
 'class':'imageOn'
 'href':'#',
});

image.html(aux);
$("#categoriasList").append(image);
```

And after appending you can attach event handler. If you attaching without creating actual element it will not be triggered. It means if you want to attach event handler in the different file you should be sure that all elements already created. Otherwise there will not be triggered.

Comment: Thanks! That's a more legible way to append the images. However, the event is not triggered yet. I tried selecting by tag, class and element, and none is working. That's weird because I also have another appended elements which is working.

Comment: How you are selecting? Using `$("img.imageOn").bind`? try `$("img.imageOn").click(function(e){ alert('it works'); })`

Comment: I've tried both of them. First, I used click - then I changed just to check it out. None is working. Don't know why because as I said, appending a list is working, the event is triggered - isn't with the image. Any other help would be very appreciate.

Comment: Make some jsFiddle testcase and i can help.